# OnRecivedError doesn't show the custom error page

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am using `onReceivedError` with a custom error page to show when internet is not available in a `WebView`. Below is the code I use for it. It doesn't work. It simply shows the webpage not available page when internet is not available.

Anyway the logcat shows me this error:

```
I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (0)
```

my code is

```
private class myWebViewBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    /*@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }*/
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        Log.e(String.valueOf(error.getErrorCode()), error.getDescription().toString());
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: i made a same thing via showing fragment over a webview

Answer (score 4):

you can change

```
view.loadUrl(...);
```

to

```
view.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html","utf-8", null );
```

where

- "file:///android_asset/" is your base url for load html
- html is your html string
- "text/html" is mime type for content
- "utf-8" is encoding style
- and last url as null, its for history reference.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/4g6H0vr5_0E

Try Following Code :

```
private class myWebViewBrowser extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {

    Log.e(String.valueOf(error.getErrorCode()), error.getDescription().toString());
    view.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html","utf-8", null );   
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why my code is not working? I mean its working sometimes, so it won't be `view.loadUrl` s problem. It has to be something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        Log.e(String.valueOf(error.getErrorCode()), error.getDescription().toString());
        view.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html","utf-8", null );   
        }
```